# What are the last two digits of 43^23^33?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the last two digits of 43^23^33? 
Anyone know it? 
Thanks

Comment: to be read $$43^{23^{33}}?$$

Comment: order of operation is important to state. is 23 raised to 33 first or is the result of 43 raised to 23 raised to 33 afterwards.

Comment: for example 2^3^4 can be either 8^4 or 2^81 depending on order

Comment: The last digit of $43^{\left(23^{33}\right)}$ is $\color{red}{7}$ because the last digit of $3^n$ is $1,3,9$ or $7$ according to $n\pmod{4}$, and $23^{33}$ is a number of the form $4k-1$.

Comment: The convention is that $\large a^{b^c}$ is interpreted as $\large a^{(b^c)}$.

Comment: As $(43^{23})^23 = 43^{23*23}$, ${43^{23}}^{23} = 43^{(23^{23})}$ is almost certainly the intent and a standard.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the question was for the last *two* digits.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: And additionally if you look at related questions shown in the sidebar on the right, there is plenty of them - they could help you answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's work $\pmod {100}$

Notice that $43^2=(50-7)^2\equiv7^2\equiv49 \pmod {100}$ and likewise $49^2\equiv1 \pmod {100}$

Therefore, $43^4\equiv 1 \pmod {100}$

$23^{33}\equiv (-1)^{33}\equiv-1 \equiv 3\pmod 4$

Hence, $43^{23^{33}}\equiv43^3\equiv49\times43\equiv1600+12\times40+27\equiv80+27\equiv 07 \pmod {100}$

Answer (score 1):

I would begin in the same way. Once we've established $43$ has order $4$ modulo $100$, we have
$$43^{23^{33}}\equiv 43^{23^{33}\bmod 4}\equiv 43^{(-1)^{33}\bmod 4}\equiv 43^{-1}\mod 100.$$
Now the *extended Euclidean algorithm* yields a *Bézout's relation* between $43$ and $100$:
   \begin{array}[t]{rlr@{}>{{}}r@{\qquad}rrrr}
\text{Successive}&\text{Divisions}& r_i & u_i & v_i & q_i\\
     \hline
  && 100 &  0 & 1 & \\
100  &= {\color{red}2} × 43 +\color{blue}{14} & 43 & 1 & 0 & \color{red}{2} \\
\hline
   43 &= {\color{red}3} × {\color{blue}{14}} + \color{blue}{1} & 14 & -2 & 1 & \color{red}3 \\
  14  &= {\color{red}{14}} × \color{blue}{1}&1 &7 & -3 &  \\
     \hline
    \end{array}

Hence the inverse of $43\bmod100$  is equal to $7$. The last two digits of $43^{23^{33}}$ are $\color{red}{07}$.